# let's encrypt installed, but with cloudflare, browser throws SSL error

Tags: lets-encrypt, cloudflare

I've installed **certbot**, and run to create certificates with cloudflare global api key:

```
certbot certonly --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials /root/.secrets/cloudflare.ini -d "mydomain.com" -d "www.mydomain.com" --preferred-challenges dns-01 --non-interactive -m "myemail@gmail.com" --agree-tos
```

it created the fullchain.pem and privkey.pem files which are I've added to my nginx configuration:

```
ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
```

nginx -t tested as successfully.

So now, SSL checker sites (and also chrome private browser) returns with `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` when I turned on the cloudflare's proxy (**set to orange cloud**) before my A record, or CNAME www.

If I turned off cloudflare's proxy (**set to gray cloud**) then everything is working, verified https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html.

Cloudflare setup right now:

- SSL > Full (tried with normal too) strict
- Edge certificates > everything turned off, no universal SSL enabled neither
- Origin server > everything turned off, no certificate added neither

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or text of the certificate itself?  Try setting your SSL setting to "Flexible" to see if that helps.